# Accidentally retracted a duplicate flag, flagged the question for moderator intervention but it got declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

Not sure if I should (or even if I'm permitted) to go into the specific questions/ share the links on Meta.

Regardless, some time ago I came across a question from a particular user. I didn't take much notice until the next day when I saw the exact same question, in the exact same format, exact same words, from the same user, but with a code tag around a URL instead (`).

I immediately flagged this as duplicate and posted a comment under the question, letting the user know that this is a duplicate question and that I was voting to close it. I downvoted and moved on.

Some time later I was looking through my recent flags and noticed that this flag had `aged away`. So I clicked on the question, clicked the flag button and accidentally pressed the 'retract flag' button.

Total accident, I sometimes have tremors which I am unable to control, resulting in misclicks and all sorts. There was no confirmation to say yes, no, are you sure? - kind of thing.

So, I thought the next best thing would be to notify a moderator to the issue, and I explained my situdation:

> Duplicate of [question url] but I accidentally retracted my closure tag

Today I logged on to see the following message for my flag:

> nopassport1 yesterday
>   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

But this was something which required moderator intervention, I specified this in my original flag. The question is an exact copy of another question, from the same user. There is no difference between the two questions. Therefore the duplicate one should be closed.

I don't understand why my flag was declined? Please could someone explain this to me? I'd like to know what I did wrong in this situation so that I do not repeat it in the future - minus the obvious not clicking the 'retract flag' button.

Comment: Moderators are no subject matter experts. They can't decide if something is a duplicate, no matter how right you are and if they would use their close vote, it is binding which is different from a close flag you would cast. At best you leave a comment pointing out the duplicate or seek assistance in a chatroom if you're hoping for a more expedite handling. Don't use moderator flags to achieve something the community can do on its own (given enough voters show up)

Comment: Understood. I wasn't aware that this was the case with moderators and closures. So in my case, I should share the question in a chat and see if people agree that this is a duplicate? Because I currently cannot flag it as a duplicate so it will go into the review queue.

Comment: sharing a link in  a chatroom and asking others to judge is indeed an option. Do check chatroom rules / etiquette. Not all rooms are open for such requests.

Comment: In regards to Andy's answer on the dupe: Where it says _"for a user posting a duplicate question repeatedly is a valid use of the mod flag"_, I believe  "repeatedly" here means "more than twice".

Comment: This didn't require moderator intervention - just the intervention of other normal users who could recognise it as a duplicate and vote to close. It's not imperative that you be one of those users.